# Unable to retrieve 'Authorization' header in AMPscript or SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

I have a CloudPage returning an error this week, which has never errored in the past.

After closer examination, I've determine the page is failing on this line of code  `%%=HTTPRequestHeader('Authorization')=%%`.

I was able to wrap the code in an SSJS try catch to get the Marketing Cloud error message.  The code executes fine if any string other than 'Authorization' is used in the call.

It seems as though something has changed on the Marketing Cloud platform.  But, I'm unable to confirm this.  Any suggestion or advice would be greatly appreciated!

**test code:**

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core","1.");
    try {
</script>

<pre>
  Content-Type = %%=HTTPRequestHeader('Content-Type')=%%
  Authorization = %%=HTTPRequestHeader('Authorization')=%%
</pre>

<script runat="server">
    } catch(e) {
      Write(Stringify(e));
    }
</script>
```

**output:**

> {"message":"An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a HTTPRequestHeader function call. See inner exception for details.","description":"ExactTarget.OMM.FunctionExecutionException: An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a HTTPRequestHeader function call. See inner exception for details.\r\n Error Code: OMM_FUNC_EXEC_ERROR\r\n - from Jint --> \r\n\r\n --- inner exception 1---\r\n\r\nExactTarget.OMM.FunctionExecutionException: An unauthorized HTTPRequestHeader has been requested.\r\n Function: HTTPRequestHeader('Authorization')\r\n LandingPageID: 0\r\n URL: [http://pub.s7.exacttarget.com:9002/REDACTED\r\n](http://pub.s7.exacttarget.com:9002/REDACTED%5Cr%5Cn) Context: LandingPage\r\n StackID: 7\r\n EnterpriseID: 12345678\r\n ClientID: 7203368\r\n Client Database ID: 718\r\n Account Type: PRO_CONNECT_CLIENT\r\n JobID: 0\r\n SubscriberID: 0\r\n Content Type: HTML\r\n MachineName: ATL1S07PGS187\r\n Error Code: OMM_UNAUTH_HTTP_REQ_HDR_ERR\r\n - from OMMCommon\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"}

Comment: The SSJS version of this call, Platform.Request.GetRequestHeader('Authorization'), does not return an error, but returns as NULL.

Comment: I have a service hosted on CloudPage with HTTPHeader.GetValue('Authorization'). It started to return NULL as well. Seems like access to that header got restricted.

Comment: I've reached to developer support. Will let you know they response.

Comment: @MateuszBartkowiak - I was just able to successfully retrieve the "Authentication" header value.  I wonder if SF is fixing this issue.

Comment: thanks for the info. Will check on Monday and if it will work will retract my reply

Comment: you're right, seems it works ok now, updated the answer

Answer (score 4):

I've got below response from support:

> Due to the changes in Authentication support that has taken place
> over the last couple of releases (Oauth 1.0 to 2.0) the Authentication
> header is no longer supported (technically is was never officially
> supported, which is why the AMPScript function returns an error).

Recommendation is to use different header to pass this data, like `X-access-token`

**EDIT:**

As of 8/17/2020 it seems that Authorization header is working properly again, and is accessible from both Ampscript and SSJS